# Show image only in progress dialog for Android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio

**Style for dialogbox**

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/loading</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

**How to Show image in progress dialog box**

i have created above custom Dialog and which i am using progressDrawable but not able to show my gif image in my progress Dialog

Need the correct assistance for it.

Comment: Can you share your code for your progressDrawable attribute? What do you see? What are you expecting to see?

Your question needs a bit more detail

Comment: in style.xml i have done this code
`<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/loading</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>`

In mainActivity class i am doing this

` ProgressDialog pd;
 pd=new ProgressDialog(this,R.style.CustomDialog);
 pd.show();`

Comment: @drawable/loading is a image inside my drawable

Comment: Please reply @jade byfield